# Verify XML field with MySQL and XSD file

Tags: mysql, xml, spring-mvc, xsd

I looked in the MySQL documentation but I didn't find an answer to my question :
I would like to know if MySQL could "check" if a field filled with XML is well formed.
Of course I would give to MySQL a XSD to verify the XML and I will use Spring MVC to manage the server's side of things.

I know it is not something I should do BUT I HAVE to do this in a school project.

rXp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, MySQL does not provide build-in functions for that. You have to query the document out of the database and use your programming language of choice to validate the XML document against a XSD.